# Seeking for advice with dealing with out of sync audio

Tags: video, audio, sync

I have a bunch of videos from games caputured with NVidia's Share.
They are trimmed using VLC.

I have one video that is 1 minute and 38 seconds long (a lot longer then the others). If I play it in VLC the sound is in sync, If I play it with Blender, windows media player or Shotcut then the sound is out of sync.

I tried to convert the video from VLC to other formats, but either I end up with 2kb files, or the sound is still out of sync in other software. So far I wasted 3 hours on this. Can someone with more experience help me with advice on what to try next?